# Spreading to make tall data wide not by collapsing rows into columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to turn a tall data set wide by merging multiple columns onto an ID.

I have been using spread but currently I just get the column that spread creates but there are still the same amount of rows as before.
I currently have:

```
  ID Code_Type Code
   1   10        4
   1    9        5 
   2    10       6
   2    9        7
```

I would like:

```
ID  Code_Type_10  Code_type_9
1       4              5
2       6              7
```

Here is my current code

```
t <- spread(df, Code_Type, Code)
```

However when I do this it creates the columns but does not compress the rows.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it creates the columns but does not compress the rows." I'm getting what seems to be your output after adding `sep = "_"` to the `spread` call

Comment: So what is happening is that I get two columns on the end of the data frame that are the Code_type Columns but the data is still tall

Comment: you should make sure that your data is properly represented by this example. `spread(df, Code_Type, Code, sep = "_")` gets your output exactly for me, but it might be due to having more columns present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a little to MDEWITT's entry

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2), 
                 "Code_Type" = c(10,9,10,9), 
                 "Code" = c(4,5,6,7))

t <- tidyr::spread(df, Code_Type, Code)
names(t)[c(2,3)] <- paste0(rep("Code_Type_", 2), names(t)[c(2,3)])

df %>% 
  mutate(Code_Type = paste0("Code_Type_", Code_Type)) %>% 
  spread(Code_Type, Code)

> t
  ID Code_Type_9 Code_Type_10
1  1           5            4
2  2           7            6
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are thinking?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Code_Type = paste0("Code_Type_", Code_Type)) %>% 
  spread(Code_Type, Code)
```

I think you would just need to add the mutate step to make it work.